# How can I configure Slime to use case sensitive symbols?

Tags: slime, common-lisp

In emacs lisp variables are not case sensitive, so if I define a variable `x`, I can access it using `X`, but I can modify the elisp behavior by `(setq readtable-case :preserve)`, is there something similar for slime?

To check case sensitivity you can run `'abcd` in the REPL and if you get `ABCD` the it's not case sensitive as by default it makes the symbols uppercase.

Comment: What do you mean by this: *"In emacs lisp variables are not case sensitive"*? Did you instead mean Common Lisp? Or did you instead mean case-insensitive? What do you mean by a *variable* being case-(in)sensitive? Do you mean that its name is? its value is (if a string)? Elisp has no `readtable-case`, so I thing you meant Common Lisp, not Emacs Lisp.

Comment: In emacs setting readtable-case made the symbols become case sensitive so I thought it was coming from elisp. It could be just related to function called on `C-x X-e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common Lisps Reader converts all symbols to uppercase, when reading them.
To use lowercase symbols in Common Lisp you have to escape them with `| |` or `\`.

So this is not an SLIME/SLY issue at all.

```
CL-USER> (defvar |x| 5)
|x|
CL-USER> |x|
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
CL-USER> (defvar \x 5)
|x|
CL-USER> \x
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
CL-USER> x
; Debugger entered on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE X {10050E7643}>
```

See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375537/why-is-common-lisp-case-insensitive

Comment: This might work. Let me try it and see. I'd have to write something to rename all the variables to `|var|` manually, or do you know if there's some automated way for that?